# Not able to enter card details in RazorPay Checkout UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, razorpay

I am using razorpay checkout.js in two react application with same strcuture

`'https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js'`

in one project I am able to enter card details in another I am not able to enter the card details (input field is focus out as soon as I tried to type).

I just copied the same code from the working project.
Is there something I am missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, another popup modal was open in the page, when I close the other popup it worked